# Как сделать чтобы пункты меню не съезжали?

Tags: html, css

[image: меню]

Пункты в меню написанный огромными буквами (uppercase). В макете задумано что при наведении на пункт меню текст становится маленьким (inset). Проблема заключается в том что при наведении текст становится маленьким тем самым ширина текста становится тоже меньше и меню начинает съезжать. Очень трудно описать это текстом, грубо говоря если будет 3 блока по ширине 50 пикс. один при наведении становится 20пикс. то другие начнут тоже немного двигаться, что-то подобное у меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задай min-width:50px для блока в котором текст и тогда съезжать не будет.

Comment: чёрт, а ты красавчик..